# How to get text from passwordbox in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to get value from passwordbox for developing a simple login functionality, but, like textbox there is no text property. So how do I get the value of password box?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `string password = yourPasswordBox.Password;`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.password%28VS.95%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

if you user caliburn micro you can do like this
example

View

`<TextBox x:Name="login"/> 
 <TextBox x:Name="key"/> 
 <Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action ConfirmButton(login.Text,key.Password)]"/>`

ViewModel

```
public void ConfirmButton(String user, String key)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("LOGIN -> USER -> " + user + " key -> "+key);


    }
```